# Unable to read a file while using relative path

Tags: rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I want to read a file inside python script in ros indigo in the following way -

```
file_name = rospy.get_param("~file", None)
```

Below is the snippet of launch file -

```
<launch>
    <arg name="file"  default="$(find kinematics)/sample/joint_states.csv" />
    <arg name="animation" default="true" />  <!-- run animation -->
    <group if="$(arg animation)">
        <node pkg="kinematics" type="trajectory.py" name="trajectory_animation" respawn="true">
            <param name="file" value="$(arg file)" />
        </node>
    </group>
</launch>
```

While providing the `file` parameter as a command line argument, it says `No such file or directory`. Below is the output of terminal -

```
ravi@ravi-pc:~/ros_ws$ roslaunch kinematics baxter.launch file:=src/../../Desktop/joint_states.csv 
  File "/home/ravi/ros_ws/src/kinematics/src/trajectory.py", line 19, in __init__
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'src/../../Desktop/joint_states.csv'
ravi@ravi-pc:~/ros_ws$ ll src/../../Desktop/joint_states.csv
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ravi ravi 179308 May 19 20:46 src/../../Desktop/joint_states.csv
ravi@ravi-pc:~/ros_ws$ roslaunch kinematics baxter.launch file:=src/kinematics/sample/joint_states.csv
  File "/home/ravi/ros_ws/src/kinematics/src/trajectory.py", line 19, in __init__
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'src/kinematics/sample/joint_states.csv'
ravi@ravi-pc:~/ros_ws$ ll src/kinematics/sample/joint_states.csv
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tom tom 179308 May 19 20:46 src/kinematics/sample/joint_states.csv
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235337/unable-to-read-a-file-while-using-relative-path/) by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1744 on 2016-05-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are probably not aware that by default, the working directory of all nodes is set to `$ROS_HOME`, which in most cases will be `$HOME/.ros`, *not* the base of your catkin workspace.

Some earlier questions and answers about this:

- [How to save file to the current directory with roslaunch?](http://answers.ros.org/question/57075)
- [roslaunch prevents node from creating/writing to file](http://answers.ros.org/question/38045)
- [Write to a file from a C++ ROS node?](http://answers.ros.org/question/11642/write-to-a-file-from-a-c-ros-node/)

Note: you *don't* want to go and change the value of `ROS_HOME`. Instead, either specify an absolute path, or place data in a package that is on the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` and use `$(find ..)/path/to/data.file` (as you are doing in your launch file). Note that the equivalent of `$(find ..)` in your launch file is `rospack find ..` on the command line.

---

Edit: and a direct link to the wiki page documenting this: [roslaunch/XML/node - Attributes](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node#Attributes). Look for the `cwd` attribute.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2016-05-27**:
Many thanks. I still didn't get the answer. One of the link suggest to provide the absolute path, which I don't prefer. Another link suggest to keep the data file inside the package and use `rospack find` command. I don't prefer this too, as the file is provided by user as input. Please suggest.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-05-27**:
There is nothing to suggest. Those are the two supported options.

> keep the data file inside **the** package

Note that the suggestion is to keep it inside **a** package, not necessarily *your* package.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-05-27**:
I've no idea of the side effects / consequences, but you could see whether you can work around this by using something like [chdir(..)](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/chdir/) or [current_path(..)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#current_path) from Boost.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-05-27**:
Another option could be to pass the `cwd` to your node as a parameter, and prefix the `file` parameter with that.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From ROS kinetic on you can use `$(eval` to check whether the path is absolute and prepend `$(env PWD)/` if it is not.
That way you can pass a file with relative path and the node will receive a full path automatically.
For your example it should look something like this:

```
<launch>
    <arg name="file" />
    <node pkg="kinematics" type="trajectory.py" name="trajectory_animation" respawn="true">
        <param name="file" value="$(arg file)" if="$(eval file[0] == '/')" />
        <param name="file" value="$(env PWD)/$(arg file)" unless="$(eval file[0] == '/')" />
    </node>
</launch>
```

Of course it would be nicer to have direct support for this mechanism in roslaunch (also in bash completion...) via something like `<arg type="file"`, but someone would have to implement it of course.

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2022-08-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-08-17**:
Appreciate your kind response. Though I completely forgot about it. It's been ages!